# how to type text in a field it is blank in selenium ide

Tags: selenium-ide

I need to type text in a field only if it is blank,if it has value proceed to next.

How to verify if field(id=Status) is empty then type a text"itemtoExpire" else continue with click id=submit button

Any suggestions using verify, gotoif, labels.

I am using selenium IDE

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the `runScript` command in Selenium IDE.

```
<tr>
  <td>runScript</td>
  <td>var val = document.getElementById('Status').value; if (val == '') { document.getElementById('Status').value = "itemtoExpire"; }</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you would require [Selenium Flow Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flow-control/) to test conditions then use

```
type | id=input_id_or_selector | value_to_time
```

Answer (score 0):

After the downloading of the plugin *Selenium IDE: Flow Control* try these commands in Selenium IDE that i think will work for your scenario.

```
 <tr>
        <td>storeText</td>
        <td>id=Status</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>gotoIf</td>
        <td>'${text}'!=''</td>
        <td>submit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>id=Status</td>
        <td>itemtoExpire</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>goto</td>
        <td>end</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>label</td>
        <td>submit</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=submit</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>label</td>
        <td>end</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```